# Scala: case classes and pattern matching

Tags: scala, generics, pattern-matching, case-class

I've created this case classes and functions in scala:

```
abstract class Building[T]
case class University[T](a: Building[T], b: Building[T], c: T) extends Building

def u[A,B](a: Building[A]): Building[B] = a match {
  case n: University[A] => University[B](n.a, n.b, n.c);
}
```

However it says this when compiling:

> [error]
>   test.scala:357:
>   type mismatch; [error]  found   : test.abc.def.University[B]
>   [error]  required: test.abc.def.Building[B]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`University` must extend `Building[T]` not just `Building`

```
case class University[T](a: Building[T], b: Building[T], c: T) extends Building[T]
```

Here is the complete code

```
abstract class Building[T]
case class University[T](a: Building[T], b: Building[T], c: T) extends Building[T]
```

In `u` function Output type is `Building[B]`. You are returning `University[B]` But `University[B]` takes a which is `Building[B]` b which is again `Building[B]` and `c` which is `B`.

`n.a` returns `Building[A]` not `Building[B]` so as `University[B]` takes two `Building[B]` and one `B`. You cannot pass `n.a`, `n.b` and `n.c` to create `university[B]`.

To make the code compile I have changed the output type and returning `University[B]`

```
def u[A,B](a: Building[A]): Building[A] = a match {
  case n: University[A] => University[A](n.a, n.b, n.c);
}
```

**Correct code**

```
abstract class Building[T]

case class University[T](a: Building[T], b: Building[T], c: T) extends Building[T]

def convert[A, B](a: A): B = ???

def bConvert[A, B](building: Building[A]): Building[B] = ???

def u[A,B](a: Building[A]): Building[B] = a match {
  case n: University[A] => University[B](bConvert(n.a), bConvert(n.b), convert(n.c));
}
```